# Search button using more than one text field Access vba

Tags: sql, vba, forms, ms-access, search

This is my code below. I am trying to search a database using two different dates, company name

I am getting an error when one of the date fields is empty or null. How can I solve this issue or bypass if the date search field is empty to ignore it in the search or search for an empty field?

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT * from qryRequestInternal where ([DateRequestSent] = #" & txt_Search_Sdate & "# AND [DateReceived] = #" & txt_Search_Rdate & "# AND (companyName like ""*" & txt_SCompNa & "*"") )"
Me.sfrmRequestInternal.Form.RecordSource = SQL
Me.sfrmRequestInternal.Form.Requery

Me.sfrmRequestInternal_col.Form.RecordSource = SQL
Me.sfrmRequestInternal_col.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: `NZ` will help i think with access, or check the values before and build the where clause from the different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check for Null values and build the SQL string based on the controls which have a value (i.e. not null).

The example below uses a helper function to build the sql string. If nothing is inserted, it will only run the the `Select * from qryRequestInternal` without any criteria.

```
Private Function SqlWhere() As String

    Dim retvalue As String
    
    'sent date
    With txt_Search_Sdate
        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            retvalue = " WHERE [DateRequestSent] = #" & Format(.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
        End If
    End With
    
    'received date
    With txt_Search_Rdate
        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            retvalue = IIf(Len(retvalue) = 0, " WHERE", retvalue & " AND") & " [DateReceived] = #" & Format(.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
        End If
    End With
    
    'company
    With txt_SCompNa
        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            retvalue = IIf(Len(retvalue) = 0, " WHERE", retvalue & " AND") & " [companyName] Like '*" & .Value & "*'"
        End If
    End With
    
    SqlWhere = retvalue
    
End Function
```

---

To call it:

```
Dim sqlString As String
    sqlString = "SELECT * from qryRequestInternal" & SqlWhere()

Debug.Print sqlString
```